# touchesBegan converts to ccTouchesBegan?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am not sure if the way that applied in touchesBegan can be applied as well in ccTouchesBegan or other touches call back. For example I have some code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
    touchPhaseText.text = @"Phase: Touches began";
    touchInfoText.text = @"";
    if(numTaps >= 2) {
        touchInfoText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d taps",numTaps]; 
        if ((numTaps == 2) && piecesOnTop) {
            // A double tap positions the three pieces in a diagonal.
            // The user will want to double tap when two or more pieces are on top of each other
            if (firstPieceView.center.x == secondPieceView.center.x)
                secondPieceView.center = CGPointMake(firstPieceView.center.x - 50, firstPieceView.center.y - 50);       
            if (firstPieceView.center.x == thirdPieceView.center.x)
                thirdPieceView.center  = CGPointMake(firstPieceView.center.x + 50, firstPieceView.center.y + 50);   
            if (secondPieceView.center.x == thirdPieceView.center.x)
                thirdPieceView.center  = CGPointMake(secondPieceView.center.x + 50, secondPieceView.center.y + 50);
            touchInstructionsText.text = @"";
        }
    } else {
        touchTrackingText.text = @"";
    }
    // Enumerate through all the touch objects.
    NSUInteger touchCount = 0;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        // Send to the dispatch method, which will make sure the appropriate subview is acted upon
        [self dispatchFirstTouchAtPoint:[touch locationInView:self] forEvent:nil];
        touchCount++;  
    }   
}
// Checks to see which view, or views, the point is in and then calls a method to perform the opening animation,
// which  makes the piece slightly larger, as if it is being picked up by the user.
-(void)dispatchFirstTouchAtPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([firstPieceView frame], touchPoint)) {
        [self animateFirstTouchAtPoint:touchPoint forView:firstPieceView];
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([secondPieceView frame], touchPoint)) {
        [self animateFirstTouchAtPoint:touchPoint forView:secondPieceView];
    } 
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([thirdPieceView frame], touchPoint)) {
        [self animateFirstTouchAtPoint:touchPoint forView:thirdPieceView];
    }

}
```

If the code like this how should I convert it to ccTouchesBegan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code should be reusable for ccTouches*. Just one additional thing is required, which is to return either a

- kEventHandled -to indicate that the event has been handled, and to stop forwarding the event to the next handler in the chain, or
- kEventIgnored - continue forwarding even to the next handler in the chain